# systemd-boot cannot find my root

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, boot, systemd-boot

I'm running Debian Testing (Buster) and I'm swapping from Grub2 to systemd as I couldn't get Grub2 to work and someone suggested I try systemd-boot instead.

The boot/root drive is on an eMMC drive on the motherboard, whilst the data drive is on an mSATA SSD.

I have systemd-boot half working and it crashes on boot with this message

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! PARTUUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 does not exist. Dropping to shell!
```

I've rebooted and managed to login using SuperGrub USB disk and I can see that the UUID does match my root partition so i don't know why it cannot find it.

/proc/cmdline output

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-5-amd64 root=UUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 ro
```

/boot and /boot/efi listings

```
kodi@BB-8:~$ ls /boot
config-4.15.0-3-amd64    grub                         System.map-4.15.0-3-amd64    vmlinuz-4.19.0-5-amd64
config-4.19.0-5-amd64    initrd.img-4.15.0-3-amd64    System.map-4.19.0-5-amd64    vmlinuz-4.9.45-ubilinux+
config-4.9.45-ubilinux+  initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64    System.map-4.9.45-ubilinux+
efi                      initrd.img-4.9.45-ubilinux+  vmlinuz-4.15.0-3-amd64

kodi@BB-8:~$ sudo ls /boot/efi
debian  EFI  loader

kodi@BB-8:~$ sudo ls /boot/efi/debian
drwx------ 2 root root     4096 Jul 16 22:31 .
drwx------ 5 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root 31595838 Jul 26 11:09 initrd.img-4.15.0-3-amd64
-rwx------ 1 root root 33228805 Jul 26 11:09 initrd.img-amd64
-rwx------ 1 root root  4933392 Jul 26 11:09 vmlinuz-4.15.0-3-amd64
-rwx------ 1 root root  5217520 Jul 26 11:09 vmlinuz-amd64
```

UUID of drives and a df command

```
kodi@BB-8:~$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 220 Jul 26 08:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 160 Jul 26 08:58 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 26 11:10 2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 -> ../../mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 42a36b04-83f8-4105-aef4-7f24b9ffff66 -> ../../sdb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 8280cf20-b70e-44f4-b092-6d3f92d54eab -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 8A84-E6C0 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 8B91-8099 -> ../../sdb4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 26 11:10 A9CE-4035 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 b2a67d10-07da-4eb4-bc16-b768084db045 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 b618f5b0-2b8a-4e33-b288-407fd4355f83 -> ../../sdb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 26 11:10 f9a00ae7-07d2-4726-947b-03a4074049dd -> ../../sda2

kodi@BB-8:~$ df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   783M   78M  705M  10% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2           57G   14G   41G  26% /
tmpfs                   3.9G   39M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               820G  555G  224G  72% /home
/dev/mmcblk0p1          511M   82M  429M  17% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2                96G   67G   24G  74% /home/hts
10.1.1.1:/media/backup  2.7T  2.3T  178G  93% /media/backup
tmpfs                   783M   44K  783M   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/dm-0               7.8G   36M  7.3G   1% /media/kodi/8280cf20-b70e-44f4-b092-6d3f92d54eab
/dev/sdb4               7.9G  4.8G  3.2G  61% /media/kodi/DATA
/dev/sdb3                14G   12G  1.7G  88% /media/kodi/boot
```

**Update: add modules**

Add to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

```
mmc_core
mmc_block
sdhci
sdhci-pci
```

Then type for 4.19.0-5 kernel

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Rebooted and I get the same message.

**UPDATE: my systemd loader.conf**

Here is my /boot/efi/loader/entries/debian.conf

```
title   Debian
linux   /debian/vmlinuz-amd64
initrd  /debian/initrd.img-amd64
options root=PARTUUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 rw
```

This is the UUID for my /dev/mmcblk0p2 eMMC device which is mounted as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On giving this another look, it seems you have a mismatch between PARTUUID=... and UUID=... and that's what's causing this problem.

You mentioned bootloader is configured with:

```
options root=PARTUUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 rw
```

But when you manage to boot it, you actually find this UUID under `/dev/disk/by-uuid`:

```
kodi@BB-8:~$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 26 11:10 2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 -> ../../mmcblk0p2
```

Furthermore, that's even listed in `/proc/cmdline` of the successful boot (I'm assuming it's the one with SuperGrub USB):

> `/proc/cmdline` output
>
> ```
> BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-5-amd64 root=UUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 ro
> ```

The two UUIDs are different. PARTUUID= is the UUID that will be found in the GPT partition table (that's why it's called "PART", because it's a property of the partition, recorded in the partition table), while UUID= is a UUID recorded in the filesystem (ext4, or xfs, or whichever filesystem you formatted the partition with) and Linux is able to read those while scanning the disks.

So, it looks like you need to fix your boot options to use UUID= instead of PARTUUID=, since the UUID you have is a *filesystem* UUID and not a *partition* UUID.

Edit file `/boot/efi/loader/entries/debian.conf` and replace the last line with:

```
options root=UUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 rw
```

That should fix your issue!

Make sure your `/etc/fstab` in the system also matches the correct tag.

You can also use the `blkid` command to inspect the UUIDs present in your partitions and filesystems. This might help you confirm that you have the correct *kind* of UUID.

For instance, using `blkid -o export` should display something like:

```
$ sudo blkid -o export
DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0p1
SEC_TYPE=msdos
LABEL=boot
UUID=9A8B-7C6D
TYPE=vfat
PARTUUID=abcd1234-01

DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0p2
UUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09
TYPE=ext4
PARTUUID=abcd1234-01

...
```

That should help you see all UUIDs with a tag that is recognized by Linux.

Comment: @fibranden thanks so much this has been bugging me for a while and I didn't know the difference between PARTUUID and UUID, now I do.

Comment: I'm glad we figured that one out! Sorry I didn't notice this at first, your investigation was quite detailed and I missed that at first look...

Answer (score 1):

The device where your root partition lives is `/dev/mmcblk0`, which is an SD card. Modules for these devices are typically not compiled into the kernel, but into external modules, so they need to be included into your initramfs (or initrd) so they can be loaded before your root filesystem can be mounted.

On Debian, you can rebuild your `initrd.img` file using the [`update-initramfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.8.en.html) command.

But first, you need to update the configuration to make sure the modules you need are going to be included into the updated initramfs.

You can either configure that using the `MODULES` directive in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and you can also list modules to load in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/modules.d/*`. See [`man initramfs.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf.5.en.html) for more details.

The modules you need are `mmc_core` and `mmc_block`. It's possible that you'll also need `sdhci` and `sdhci-pci`, so consider listing those as well.

Once you get your config updated, regenerate the initramfs for the kernel version you're trying to boot, with:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.19.0-5-amd64
```

Or, to regenerate the initramfs files for all kernels:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Hopefully, this is all you need for the kernel to find the root partition while booting.

Comment: I still get the same problem even with those modules loaded in the initramfs. I managed to do a lsmod whilst sitting in the initramfs and proved that those modules are loading but I still get the same problem.

Comment: I think the systemd-boot is looking in the /boot/efi/debian directory but the updated files for kernels is going into the /boot directory. Should I copy those kernels from /boot to /boot/efi/debian?

Comment: I ended up copying these over to /boot/efi/debian and it's still broken

Comment: @map7 Can you try adding a `rootdelay=` to the options? In `/boot/efi/loader/entries/debian.conf`, change the last line to `options root=PARTUUID=2251a5a4-6c18-425c-9264-df971d297b09 rw
rootdelay=15`, if that doesn't work, try increasing it (maybe doubling it?) to see if that helps... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some misunderstanding here so far.  The missing modules that are mentioned in the output are *not* kernel modules, but *boot loader* modules.  What I see is the boot loader having issues finding the kernel image itself, perhaps because it cannot cope with the device it is on.  At this stage, kernel modules are irrelevant.

I am not familiar with systemd-boot at all, but would expect that any modules you have to add go somewhere in `/boot/efi/` on the partition that the bootloader is installed on.  This is typically a FAT32-partition on your boot device.